# Flash Builder 4 changes not compiled

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, incremental-build, flashbuilder4

Im using Flash Builder 4 on the Mac and I have a worrisome problem: The compiler is sometimes not detecting my code changes.

For example I might write some code, compile and run, then add some logging statements, but they will not print. After a clean compile everything runs as expected.

I cannot see a pattern to the exclusion of changes. I'm wondering if anyone else is having the same problem?

Details:

- Flash Bulider 4
- Pure AS3 project targetting Flex3.5 SDK
- Max OS X Snow Leopard
- My code does not use semicolons to terminate statements

Comment: I've seen this too, however with Flex projects and I *do* terminate statements with semicolons. It's not been frequent however and I've written it off as temporary lapses in judgement by Flash Builder. I know this won't help much, but at least yours is not an isolated incident. My problem just went away so I unfortunately don't have a solution for you, just sympathies.

Comment: For anybody else out there: This seems to be caused by using Flex SDK 3.5 in Flash Builder 4. Not sure if this is a Mac specific issue. I've switch over to using Flex SDK 4.0 and the problem has not occurred since. I'll post an actual answer when I have used it some more.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with the SDK settings selected for the Compiler.

Try going to 'Project' > 'Properties' > 'ActionScript Compiler'.
Now, in the 'Flex SDK section', try changing the SDK. Click on 'Apply'.
This will force FB to rebuild all settings for the project.

You can try again. FB should now have started compiling with latest code changes again.

Please Note: This is not a permanent fix though!
In case the problem re-occurs, you'll need to again perform the steps mentioned above to get FB back on track.

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem but this won't fix it. I do a clean and build all, and everything gets deleted and copied again except for the SWF file which remains untouched. What can I do? if I delete the SWF FB doesn't even try to re build it.

Answer (score 2):

As bad as it sounds, I am now used to this behavior, I use FB4 on a Mac , but remember having the same issue with Flex.

Practically, I keep clearing the browser cache and cleaning the project. I have thought about adding some random number after the swf url so that it never gets cached but haven't implemented it yet. Force of habit I guess, clearing the cache & cleaning the project has become such a routine!